# Class attributes based on variables (getattr)

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, gpio

I struggle with using variables (ultimately dictionary) for dynamically compose and access class attributes using getattr:

```
from gpiozero import PiStop

lights = PiStop('A+')

# working call: lights.red.on()

var = 'red.on'
getattr(lights(), var) # doesn't work - error
```

I cannot find proper syntax...

Comment: If `red` is an attribute of `lights`, and `lights.red` has an method called `on`, you might be looking for something like `getattr(getattr(lights, 'red'), 'on')()`

Comment: Also keep in mind that `gettattr` without a "default" (`getattr(obj,'<attr_name>')` ) raises an error, you should either check for the attr with `hasattr` or give it a default and check you din't get that.

Answer (score 1):

You have **two** attributes being accessed; `lights.red` is *one* such attribute, and on the *result* of that access, you then apply another attribute access, so `<result>.on`.

You need to use separate `getattr()` calls to achieve the same.

You could split on the `'.'` dot in `var` and apply each name separately, in a loop:

```
result = lights()
for name in var.split('.'):
    result = getattr(result, name)
```

This allows for `var` to be set to any number of nested attributes.